# Large timer interrupt instructions

Tags: microcontroller, timer, interrupts, counter

Assume that it takes the micro-controller **1 microsecond** to execute an instruction and the **timer overflow** has also been set to **1 microsecond** and in the **timer interrupt handler** we have some instructions which take **100 microsecond** to be executed.

What will happen in this case if the interrupt handler starts?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: It depends on how you've set up interrupt handling in your micro... best case would be an endless loop continually executing the interrupt handler. Worst case would probably be a stack overflow and what that leads to depends on your micro - maybe a reset, maybe a halt... A definitive answer would need a lot more detail from you.

Comment: It depends on the microcontroller. Can you be more specific? But in general, if you only have time to execute one instruction, it had better be a "return from interrupt" instruction. But that doesn't give you any opportunity to do anything else that might be useful.

Comment: Is your CLK frq 1MHz?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers,
I just wanted to know how is the mechanism which I somehow got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First microsecond: Enter ISR and process 100 microseconds worth of instruction(dont see why you intend on doing this though you know it will exceed 1 microsecond).
Renter back ISR and do the same 100 microseconds instruction.

In other words,you will **NEVER** enter main().Atleast this is what happens on LPC1778.

Instead, if you know you ISR takes 100 microseconds to complete, its a general practice to keep an interrupt time more than 100 microseconds so that the main() can execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers,
Actually I'm not intentionally mess around with ISR, I just wanted to know how is the system working? just to be careful about my programming in case of shorting in memory and stuff :-)

Comment: Hope it answered your question

Comment: Note, that there are some microcontrollers (Atmel, if I remember correctly) which guarantee that one instruction will be executed after an interrupt before entering the next one. Even if it's so, this still is not much of a help in this case, because main() will be executed one instruction at a time every 100 µs which could mean a lot of time for just one pass.